# Dual Monitor Slideshows

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors, slideshow

So I have dual monitors and I'd like to run a slideshow on one window while the other stays active so I can still do stuff on it.

I know that you can move the slideshow across the monitors with <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Key</kbd> but it the default slideshow on Windows disables the other monitor. So if I play it on the default (left) monitor, the right is disabled and likewise the other way around.

Is there a way I can have my monitor enabled while playing a slideshow on my right monitor?

Comment: What do you mean the right monitor is disabled? I attemped the shortcut in question, it does not switch the monitor the presentation is on, nor does it disable my other monitor.

Comment: In Windows 7 Home Premium it does, not sure about any other version. But on dual monitors, it defaults to the left monitor and disables the right.